# Adding data to queryset in ModelViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My `ViewSet` has two methods implemented: `list()` and `get_queryset()`.

`queryset` operates on all objects of a model. It's used for filtering data without usage of *DjangoFilterBackend*.

I'm interested in adding an extra field to the response when specific quantity of records is returned, e.g.:

```py
if len(queryset) > 1:
  resp = {"message": "Narrow down filter criteria."}
elif len(queryset) == 0:
  resp = {"message": "No results found."}
else:
  resp = {"message": "OK"}
```

When I run the code, prints placed in `list()` and `get_queryset()` appear in the following order:

```
'list()' checking in...  
'get_queryset() checking in...
```

It seems that all changes applied in `list()` method are overwritten by `get_queryset()`. Otherwise, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36558445/1737830) would have helped.

Is there any other way to return the queryset enriched by additional data, `resp` in this case?

Comment: Maybe this question and answer helps you; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58119474/drf-api-return-a-list-with-filtered-lists. Otherwise you can add an extra field in your serializer.

Comment: The problem here is, that when `list()` method gets called, the queryset data isn't known yet, so there is no possibility to evaluate desired numbers. Thanks for the link though, I might use that knowledge somewhere else :-)